# Does the connectionManagement config apply to SqlConnections?

Tags: .net, sqlconnection

In a .NET 4 application, does the default limit of 2 connections to a host (via `<system.net><connectionManagement>`) apply to a `SqlConnection` pool?

Comment: Good question - so strange to stumble across such a setting and consider its potentially massive impact.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `SqlConnection` creates connections using Win32 API, not `System.Net`.